# vbscript to detect webpage Javascript alert and close it

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I have written a vbscript (.vbs) to login to web application and then auto click on some buttons in loop. The last button displays a Javascript alert() box which shows a confirmation message. This alert() box must be closed to loop again same process.

So my problem is that my vbscript is not able to detect this javascript alert() box and closes it. I have tried to close with SendKeys "{ENTER}" option also.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098515/automatically-closing-an-excel-popup-prompt-using-vbscript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098515/automatically-closing-an-excel-popup-prompt-using-vbscript)

Comment: Thanks for reply but this is not working in my case...