# How to detect save as dialog box in IE using Vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am writing a simple vbscript as shown below to Click "Save" on the save dialog box that opens whenever we click on a download in IE but so far it's not working

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.AppActivate ("Internet Explorer")
WScript.Sleep 10000
WshShell.SendKeys "%S"
```

Comment: This question is almost being asked daily any more. :) See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098515/automatically-closing-an-excel-popup-prompt-using-vbscript).

Comment: mmm..I tried using ALT+S but it doesn't detect the save dialog box

Comment: See. Link. Posted. Above. ^ It's right there. ^