# Need help identifying and closing a warning that appears at random

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I have a warning pop up that appears at random on my windows application(this warning is necessary) which needs associated hardware to fix the issue related with warning. This will not let the application work until its closed.

Anyway, my problem is when I am running another script, verifying something on the application, I need a way to look out for this dialog and close it while the script is running. Are there any ways/methods/keywords to do this?

Like I said, this warning happens at random so I cannot put the logic for it in one place in the script and expect it to work nor I can put it on every line. Any ideas on how to handle this? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer [VBScript to detect an open messagebox and close it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261157/vbscript-to-detect-an-open-messagebox-and-close-it)

Another solution

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace HandleDynamicDialog
{
    public class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

        private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;

        private const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length == 2)
            {
                //Pass your dialog class and title as command line arguments from uft script.
                string targetDialogClass = args[0];
                string targetDialogTitle = args[1];
                //Verify UFT is launched 
                bool uftVisible = IsUftVisible();
                while (uftVisible)
                {
                    //Close the warning dialog
                    CloseDialog(targetDialogClass, targetDialogTitle);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Close dialog using API
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dialogClass"></param>
        /// <param name="dialogTitle"></param>
        public static void CloseDialog(string dialogClass, string dialogTitle)
        {
            try
            {
                int winHandle = FindWindow(dialogClass, dialogTitle);
                if (winHandle > 0)
                {
                    SendMessage(winHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //Exception
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Verify UFT is visible or not
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool IsUftVisible()
        {
            return Process.GetProcesses().Any(p => p.MainWindowTitle.Contains("HP Unified Functional Testing"));
        }
    }
}
```

From UFT

```
Call HandleDynamicDialog("CalcFrame","Calculator")
Public Sub HandleDynamicDialog(ByVal dialogClass,ByVal dialogTitle)
    Dim objShell
    Dim strCommandLineString
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")    
    strCommandLineString = "C:\HandleWarningDialog.exe " & dialogClass & " " & dialogTitle
    SystemUtil.CloseProcessByName "HandleWarningDialog.exe"
    objShell.Exec(strCommandLineString)
    Set objShell = Nothing  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Explore 'Recovery Scenarios' in UFT. 
They are there for precisely this reason- Exception handling.